# (Mathematica) RegionPlot3D + DiscretizeRegion + ImplicitRegion does not show any tick marks for axes

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

Running the following snippet

```
region = ImplicitRegion[x - y + z == 0, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}}];
RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion[region]]
```

Outputs

[3D image of a plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcyGb.png)

I want to have tick marks and to retain the functionality of RegionPlot3D (to be able to change the color, etc.). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing preventing you from using all of the available options to `RegionPlot3D` documented [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html).

```
RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion[region], PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> None,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.75]]]
```

[image]